# Is there any better usable and mobile friendly solution for textarea input?

Tags: mobile-web, mobile-first

I have searched on few solutions for a touch friendly and mobile-friendly textarea input. But all textarea inputs having a poor usability when used in mobile devices. Apple devices doesn't even shows the draggable handle. Is there any **UX-Friendly solution** for these **textarea** input filed?

[image]

I believe something like below would be helpful,

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to understand the context.. why do you want to provide a draggable option to the user?

Comment: Because our application uses text areas and it's been used in tablet devices and also desktops where we need to expand the textarea when needed manually (specifically not automatically. That's a requirement actually)

Comment: I notice that stackexchange answer box has dragabble handler like that, but not the comment box. Does anyone know what library is it?

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic text input field might be best.

Take a look here: https://api.jquerymobile.com/textinput/

The methods and options associated with the text input in the above link allow you to auto-resize boxes when their display length is reached, includes an easy to use clear button within the input itself (cuts down on extra buttons on the front-end) and also an option to have a "mini" version.

Check it out, it's specifically designed for mobile devices.